# How do I make a animation splash screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation

How do I make a animation splash screen?

I want my app to look more professional, so I decided to add a splash screen. How should I  implementat a animation splash screen?

Comment: That depends what kind of animation you want. The question is vague

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create a new Activity called, for example, "SplashScreen".
Then modify your xml file as you want (design it).

I suppose that you want to show that screen when the app is opened and for a limited time.

Soy first yo have to change the priority screen in your AndroidManifest file. Take a look at this code:

```
<application
    ...
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

As you can see, you have to put your "SplahScreen" activity just before "intent-filter".

In your Splashscreen java file you should write something like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Duration of splash in milliseconds**/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY = 1000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        /* Start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close Splash-Screen after SPLAH_DISPLAY milliseconds*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 It just simple 
add this anmiation in image view ,textview and etc...
 ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), 
         R.anim.clockwise);
      image.startAnimation(animation1);


 and this clockwise desgin class have te code that is

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fromDegrees="0"
      android:toDegrees="360"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:duration="5000" >
   </rotate>
   
   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:startOffset="5000"
      android:fromDegrees="360"
      android:toDegrees="0"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:duration="5000" >
   </rotate>
   
</set>
```